# How can we convert the list of dates into yyyymmdd format using for loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, date-conversion

For conversion of any given date into yyyymmdd, we can do like date -d " Tue Apr 9 16:19:48 IST 2019 " "+%Y%m%d". But how can we convert the list of dates into yyyymmdd format using for loop in bash?

```
for i in `cat create_time`;do date -d " $i  " "+%Y%m%d"; done
```

create_time is the file contains date.

```
for i in `cat create_time`;do date -j -f " $i  " "+%Y%m%d"; done
```

The result should be like this format 20190409 for all the given dates.

Answer (score 2):

`date -f create_time "+%Y%m%d"` prints that format for every date line in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want this for all the date having default format like "Wed Apr 10 16:20:04 IST 2019" should into 20190410 format and the there are lot of default dates into the create_time file.So I didn't found the solution by using for loop. I get the solution by using while loop.  Syntax is: while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do date -d " $line " "+%Y%m%d" ; done < create_time

Comment: because for loop does not understands a particular default date into a single line. So thats why I used while loop instead of for loop.